# access document.getElementById(' in php

Tags: file, document, plupload

I am trying to access an element in php for document.getElementById( the element is file.name and the id is 'filelist' but the php does not accept the code for the line shown below, can someone advise on the correct syntax as everything I have tried returns null

```
$data = "document.getElementById("filelist").innerHTML += '<br/>' + file.name";
```

Comment: You are probably very very far from anything meaningful if you asked such a question. if you need to retrieve a given element from a dom, you should have a dom to begin with. How do you happen to have a dom in the php side of processing?

Comment: The dom is in the html form custom.html document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>'; the element is file.naame and iI want to access thois in my phppage update.php with the code in my post

Comment: yes but such html is the page that gets rendered to the client. The php code usually deals with parameters coming from http requests. Your context is unclear and that question just sounds crazy. You (almost) never have to deal with html elements in php. You have to compose http responses containing html but that's usually a task fulfilled with a templating engine. So to make it short.. your problem is unclear and the way it was described isn't enough to make a correct guess

Comment: The html is a file uploader html form  with browse and upload buttons, inside the html code is the dom as I have mentioned, in that dom is an element called file.name. I want to access that name in the php file that uploads the file

Answer (score 0):

Diego De Vita, that guy that you commented, was 'very very far from anything meaningful' in a galaxy far, far away, happened to fix the issue, never underestimate the crazies of this world, here is the fix.

In plupload there is a main upload script called upload.php and this is the code that renames the uploaded file to a meaningless code i. e.
file_6272e003ad256 and this is the code in upload.php that renames that file id name

```
// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
```

So, search this file for the word filename

```
    // What to look for
$search = 'filename';
// Read from file
$lines = file('file_6272e003ad256');
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
    echo $line;
}
```

Then extract the phrase between the double quotes and this is the filename to rename the file with

```
rename($filePath, $original_filename);
```